# Delete a form before submission

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page that loads sections through AJAX

For example:

```
<!-- Email Section -->
<div id=\"email-container\" class=\"body-container hidden\">

</div>

<!-- Users Section -->
<div id=\"user\" class=\"body-container hidden\">

</div>

<!-- File-Upload Section -->
<div id="upload-container" class="body-container hidden">

</div>
```

When the user clicks on a link, the "old" section goes away and the "new" section appears. The "new" section is loaded and overwrites any data that may have been there before...

```
function showSection(section, link) {
    $(".body-container").addClass('hidden');
        $("#" + section + "-container").removeClass('hidden');
        $(".menu-item").removeClass('current-menu-item');
        $("#" + link).addClass('current-menu-item');

        var jqxhr = $.get("./sections/" + section)
            .done(function (response) {
                $("#" + section + "-container").html(response);
            })
            .fail(function () { 
                // blah  
            });
```

On the upload section, I have a form and it's submitted through AJAX.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function() {
    var form_data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            // do stuff with response. Don't care if it fails for now
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

My problem is that if I load this upload page more than once, more than one form is created and thus the same information is sent and uploaded multiple times.

How can I delete the old forms that were created before so only ONE form is submitted each time the user clicks "submit", regardless of how many times the section has been loaded?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's exactly what this does: `$("#" + section + "-container").html(response);`  It replaces the existing HTML in that element with the new HTML.  Can you test it?  "Load" the "upload" section twice.  What exact HTML was returned from the server each time?  What is the resulting state of the DOM after each one?  What does each AJAX POST from the form submit end up containing?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, yes it replaces the HTML each time. Lets say that the page loaded has a blank text area and I put stuff in that text area then click the link to "reload" the page. All the text goes away. Basically, the section starts from scratch and I cannot find any remnants of the "old" section. But it seems that that form lingers and I am not sure why.

Comment: @David to add more to that last comment... when I click on submit the data on the page currently is what gets submitted. If I have loaded that section 3 times, the data is submitted 3 times. If I refresh the entire page and load the upload section (just once) the data is submitted once. 
Does that answer your question or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: When you say the data is submitted three times, do you mean a single AJAX request with three forms worth of data (all different)?  Three AJAX requests with three different sets of data?  Three AJAX requests with the same set of data?  Something else?  Also, is that jQuery AJAX code being loaded into the page once?  Or each time that “section” loads?  If the latter, it would be creating a new event handler every time.

Comment: @David it submits the SAME data - whatever is currently in the section form. 
Yes, that section is being loaded each time, it's in the upload "section". I didn't think that would be the issue... let me try to put it in the main page and see what happens.

Comment: @David Yep, that was it. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to destroy the old handler so I can leave that code in that section and NOT have this issue? Please submit an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments on the question, it looks like the root of the problem is this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function() {
    //...
});
```

Since this is part of the content being loaded via AJAX, it's executing every time that content loads.  Specifically what this is doing is adding a `submit` handler to the `document` element.  So each time the content loads, another `submit` handler is added.  When all of those handlers execute, they all do the same thing.

If you *really* want the handler to be included in the content, bind directly to the element:

```
$('#upload').on('submit', function() {
    //...
});
```

As long as the `#upload` element is destroyed and a new one created each time the content is loaded, any handlers attached to that element will be destroyed as well.

However, I'd honestly recommend another approach.  Separate the functionality from the content.  Keep your `submit` handler on `document` as it already is, but move that code into the overall "parent" page instead of in the dynamically loaded content.  That way it only executes once when the page loads and doesn't need to execute again.

Refresh the *content* as often as you like, but define the overall *functionality* once.